# Contrasting trends in NDVI time series between Sentinel-2 and Landsat in Google Earth Engine

Tags: time-series, libgee

I have been testing the code from GEE documentation https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/time-series-modeling

The code originally is for Landsat so the trend is going up, but when I change and modify for Sentinel-2 the trend is going down.

The ROI and time interval are the same in both cases, and I get similar seasonality for them, but with inverted trend.

why is the reason of that difference? Is there any detail that I am not considering about Landsat and Sentinel differences?